# How do I subset a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, subset

How do I subset a matrix to get a vector?

```
> (m <- matrix(1:15,nrow=5,ncol=3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15
> (v <- c(1,3))
[1] 1 3
> (u <- c(2,4))
[1] 2 4
```

what I want is the *vector*:

```
> c(m[2,1],m[4,3])
[1]  2 14
```

but what I get is a matrix:

```
> m[u,v]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   12
[2,]    4   14
```

I guess I can use `diag` but I would rather do it in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you are passing a matrix of indices:

```
> m[cbind(u,v)]
[1]  2 14
```

For a single point, transpose gives you a matrix:

```
> m[t(c(4,3))]
[1] 14
> m[t(c(2,1))]
[1] 2
```